# LogCat not displaying anything after crash/reinstall

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, logcat

First off, as background: I am on a Mac, running OS X 10.6.7. Using Eclipse for an Android Development class I'm in (and hopefully eventually to actually develop directly for Android).

I had a nasty crash of Eclipse a few days ago, and after restarting I stopped getting any output from LogCat whatsoever. I tried everything I could think of, and I couldn't get anything at all to show up in the log. I tried a nuke-it-from-orbit reinstall of Eclipse, and it's at least made a little bit of a difference. When I run this code snippet I came up with to test things:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class LogTester extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String TAG = "LogTester";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d(TAG, "Activity was created");
        Log.d(TAG, "Anybody Home?");  
    }
}
```

...it shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgCiG.jpg) (apparently I can't post images directly as a noob), but when I actually click on the LogTester tab of LogCat, [I see nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd4av.jpg). The same thing vice-versa when I click back over to the main log tab, which as you can see should have 11 new items in it.

I tried changing the font since maybe there was some sort of issue with displaying the font, and I've heard there are weird issues with fonts and 10.6.7. But I get a "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench"." error and a complete refusal to change the font type. I can't figure out where Eclipse hides this preference so I can try and fiddle with it manually.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions as to things I should try next? This is absolutely maddening. Thanks!

*UPDATE (3/31 1am): I deleted and recreated my AVM for about the 15th time and LogCat suddenly started working. Hell if I know why, but I'm not questioning it.*

Answer (score 9):

try switching to `DDMS perspective` and click on your active emulator in the `Device tab`. Your Logcat should refresh then.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned I already tried this and it doesn't work since it's a commonly suggested remedy. Same deal as here: http://i.imgur.com/VgCiG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but a filter got turned on for some reason using Firebase which really confused me for a few mintues while I tried to figure out what was going on.

Here's where you change the filter (in the android monitor panel):

[image: change filter]